# Snowflake: Configure Microsoft Azure AD for External OAuth - admin consent

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-azure.html) guide to configure Microsoft Azure AD for external OAuth in Snowflake.
I'm pretty sure that I followed all the steps because tried that meticulously on three Azure subscriptions and got the same result.

Every time I got stuck at the [testing procedure](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-azure.html#testing-procedure) section where I'm supposed to send a request to Azure AD to get an access token:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" \
  --data-urlencode "client_id=<OAUTH_CLIENT_ID>" \
  --data-urlencode "client_secret=<OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET>" \
  --data-urlencode "username=<AZURE_AD_USER>" \
  --data-urlencode "password=<AZURE_AD_USER_PASSWORD>" \
  --data-urlencode "grant_type=password" \
  --data-urlencode "scope=session:role:analyst" \
  '<AZURE_AD_OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT>'
```

I am a subscription owner and definitely granted admin access to the `session:role:analyst` scope:
[image]

However, instead of the access token, I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '...' named 'Snowflake OAuth Client'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: ...\r\nCorrelation ID: ...\r\nTimestamp: ...",
    "error_codes": [
        65001
    ],
    "timestamp": "...",
    "trace_id": "...",
    "correlation_id": "...",
    "suberror": "consent_required"
}
```

Tried to grant the consent by reaching [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}/adminconsent?client_id={{client_id}}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7Btenant_id%7D%7D/adminconsent?client_id=%7B%7Bclient_id%7D%7D) and after granting the consent, got an error: `AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application.`

Found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/183594/aadsts500113-no-reply-address-is-registered-for-th.html) and added the return URL http://localhost/ (without a clear understanding of why). Granted the consent again and was redirected to http://localhost/?admin_consent=True&tenant={{tenant_id}}# which, I suppose, is fine.

But I still get `AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application`.

Reached to Microsoft documentation and figured out that using `grant_type=password` [is not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) - makes sense.

Tried `grant_type=client` credentials:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id={{client_id}}' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret={{client_secret}}'
```

Got the access token, but attempts to connect to Snowflake with a connection string like:

```
connection.ConnectionString = $"account={account};host={host};authenticator=oauth;user={oauthUser};token={token};";
```

Throw `Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException: 'Invalid OAuth access token.`.

I suspect this is because `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`, but replacing it with `session:scope:analyst` brings this:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_scope",
    "error_description": "AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope session:scope:analyst is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI).\r\nTrace ID: ...\r\nCorrelation ID: ...\r\nTimestamp: ...",
    "error_codes": [
        1002012
    ],
    "timestamp": "...",
    "trace_id": "...",
    "correlation_id": "..."
}
```

Since I already deviated from the official Snowflake guide, I'm asking the community for help with this issue. Thank you in in advance!

Answer (score 2):

When obtaining an access token with the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow (which is *not* recommended and you really shouldn't do), the resulting access token is for accessing a resource (API) on behalf of the signed-in user. In the Microsoft identity platform, access on behalf of a user requires the client application be granted at least one *delegated* permissions to the requested resource.

In your screenshot, we see that the permission you granted for "Snowflake OAuth Resource" is an *application* permission (aka "app role").

You need to do two things:

1. On the resource app's app registration, make sure you followed sub-step 10 under [Step 1: Configure the OAuth Resource in Azure AD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-azure.html#step-1-configure-the-oauth-resource-in-azure-ad), and defined "session:scope:analyst" as a delegated permission (scope).
2. In the client's app registration, under API permissions, choose the corresponding *delegated* permission for the resource, and grant it.

Then, when you go to test obtaining the token, make sure the "scope" parameter is the full scope value, including the resource's identifier URI (which you defined in sub-step 9). For example, if your identifier URI is `https://my.snowflake.example.com`, then the "scope" value would be `https://my.snowflake.example.com/session:role:analyst` and your cURL request would be:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" \
  --data-urlencode "client_id=<OAUTH_CLIENT_ID>" \
  --data-urlencode "client_secret=<OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET>" \
  --data-urlencode "username=<AZURE_AD_USER>" \
  --data-urlencode "password=<AZURE_AD_USER_PASSWORD>" \
  --data-urlencode "grant_type=password" \
  --data-urlencode "scope=https://my.snowflake.example.com/session:role:analyst" \
  '<AZURE_AD_OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT>'
```

**WARNING**: The Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow is not recommended. I suggest reaching out to app publishers who are suggesting you use this flow. Here is [Microsoft's warning on the subject](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc):

> Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most scenarios, more secure alternatives are available and recommended. This flow requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries risks which are not present in other flows. You should only use this flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

Comment: Since the Resource Owner Password Credentials is not recommended. Does that mean we should follow this [Create-External-OAuth-Token-Using-Azure-AD-For-The-OAuth-Client-Itself)](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Create-External-OAuth-Token-Using-Azure-AD-For-The-OAuth-Client-Itself) to support oauth on behalf of client itself?

Comment: Basically, yes. The instructions in that link are a outdated (e.g. Section 1, steps 7-9 can replaced with clicking on "App roles" to add the app role, there's no need to manually edit the manifest.) In Section 2, steps 8-20 are only necessary if you're *also* using delegated access tokens to access Snowflake. Lastly, you don't actually need to manually decode a token to learn what the `sub` value is: it's the client's service principal object ID, listed under Enterprise apps > (search for the client) > Properties.

Answer (score 0):

If the set up is still configured for "password" type grant credentials then the issue there is with the scope which should be set up on AAD and passed as follows:

```
**session:role-<name>**
```

Note, that the hyphen between role and name and it's not a colon.

In your setup, it seems to be set up and passed as:

```
session:role:<name>
```

I think, it would be much more easier to fix this issue by checking the steps done on your environment with the details here:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/External-oAuth-Token-Generation-using-Azure-AD

Comment: Thank you, Srinath! I use this guide where they recommend adding `session:role:analyst` to `appRoles`. I tried `session:scope-analyst` but have got the same effect.

Comment: Is the role "analyst" created on SF side and assigned to the user for whom this token is being generated? The basic premise is that the token will hold the user information along with the role and match it with the AAD application to see if it gets validated.